# How do I design a database for storing OAuth2 client details mapped to a given user using MySQL and Spring-OAuth2?

Tags: java, mysql, oauth-2.0, spring-data-jpa, spring-security-oauth2

## Background

I am trying to make a public facing API that is gated behind an OAuth2 workflow. I've found example database designs using JPA Repositories/Spring-OAuth2, which is the framework that I'm using. I basically have [this application](https://github.com/rrohitramsen/spring-boot-oauth2-jwt-swagger-ui/tree/master/authentication), which is currently using an InMemory authentication, which I'm trying to convert to pull the data from a database using JPA Repositories and a relational database design.

I did find [this guy](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/test/resources/schema.sql), but the problem is that it doesn't account for how the data is related to one another.

IE I was hoping that I could split the scopes into a separate table so it'd be as simple as adding additional scopes that are available for apps later on. I was also thinking of adding support for having types of OAuth clients, such as bots, website, desktop app, mobile app, etc.

I'm assuming there is some sort of a relationship between `oauth_approvals`, `oauth_refresh_token`, `oauth_client_token` and `oauth_client_details`. I want to also make sure that it's possible to map an oauth client to a `user`. Ultimately I'd like them to be able to have multiple clients.

*For my current use case it's definitely overkill to have this flow, but I am using this application to learn about different technologies.*

## What I currently have

I'm sure this can be done better, if so how?

[image: current ER Diagram]

## Questions

- How do I properly make the relationship between the different components of an oauth client?
- How can I make this so that I properly allow a user to have many clients?
- How would I be able to dynamically get a client from the database, or is this handled through `ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer.jdbc()`?
- How would I be able to add types of clients to the flow?

If you have additional questions let me know and I'll be more than happy to update my question.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @user1450740 I haven't found an answer for this yet.

Comment: And what do you do?